# $. syntax for jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

I have a code snippet I came across when learning jQuery. I am familiar with jQuery's basic selector syntax `$('element')`, but I do not know what the `$.` syntax means and here is an example of it. Could someone explain the 1st and 4th lines in depth please?

```
var $ = function(a) {
    alert(a);
}
$.add = function(a,b) {
    return a + b; 
}
```

More specifically how can you declare a variable with just `$` in the 1st line and what does $.add mean. 
Thanks a bunch!
This is based on a post I found [JQuery $. meaning](https://forums.asp.net/t/1712958.aspx?JQuery%20meaning)
Reading the comments I see the key misunderstanding is that I didnt know you can have a $ and it doesnt necessarily refer to jquery. Im sorry for not knowing any better, but I dont see the need for several downvotes on my first ever post.

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery. If you use jQuery, then this code will redefine `$` and do something unrelated with it.

Comment: Where did you come across this snippet?  Are you sure that snippet is using jQuery?  This just sets a function to a variable defined by `$` and then attaches another function to the `$` at `$.add`.  It isn't necessarily jQuery.

Comment: You're not using jQuery in this code.  You're just defining a variable called `$` and using it.  jQuery has no exclusive claim to that variable name.

Comment: This looks like legitimate question from a beginner

Comment: The answer from your own edit with the source link, *directly under that code*:  **now we have built or own $ object which we can call.**

Comment: It makes me sad that this question got so many down votes and comments that assume that everyone should know that functions in javascript are just first-class objects that you can assign properties to, and that ```$``` is a valid variable name. This question is about the syntax that jquery uses, and is perfectly valid for a beginner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For first you can think about `$` as another valid name for Javascript variable.

As you know `functions` in Javascript are *callable objects*. You can have additional properties and functions defined in the `function` object. In your case you have a reference with name `$` to a function. `$.add` - and this adds a new property into the object `$` with name `add` which refers to another function